# Combining images

Tags: iphone, image, uiimageview, uiimage

I want to place the picked image on top of another image, so that my picked image will be placed  in some sort of frame I made in Photoshop. After combining the images I want to save it to the disk.

Does anyone know how to do it, or maybe have a link to examples?

Answer (score 1):

You can just layer the two images on top of each other, first add the frame image, then add the image with the photo...

Heres sample code

Assuming your 2 images are already sized correctly to fit one on top of t he other, this code would be  in a view controller

```
UIImageView *frame=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame.png"]];
UIImageView *pic=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic.png"]];
frame.center=[self.view center];
pic.center=[self.view center];
[self.view addSubview:frame];
[self.view addSubview:pic];
```

here it is, memory managment has not been written in..

Comment: Great, i am going to try that out!, i was allready trying things with Quartz and trying to mask the images ontop of each other, but i am going to give this a go. thanks.

Comment: I forget to mention that i wanted to save the two combined images to the disk, can i do that with your method?

Comment: No it does not, You want to create an image from the two images?

Comment: Yes i want to create an image from two images, i am not so good in english so thats way i am so unclear, sorry.

Comment: thats going to  be a  little more complicated

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the picture UIImageView directly the the frame UIImageView: same as Daniel's suggestion above, but [frame.view addSubview: pic]  instead.